# nix-shell for perlPackages

Tags: nix, nixos, nixpkgs

## problem

i want to play with a perl package called `Mail::SPF` and there is a Build.PL issue. now i would like to modify the source before running the `buildPhase`.

for c/c++ based projects this is working well but for perl it fails:

```
nix-shell -I nixpkgs=nixpkgs_spamassassin/ -A perlPackages.YAML
error: attribute ‘perlPackages’ in selection path ‘perlPackages.YAML’ not found
```

so what am i doing wrong?

## nix-env

```
nix-env -I nixpkgs=nixpkgs_spamassassin/ -f nixpkgs_spamassassin/ -qaP | grep MailSPF
perlPackages.MailSPF                                      perl-Mail-SPF-v2.9.0
```

Comment: for the time being i've copied the source to to home folder and am now pointing `src = /root/nixops/Mail-SPF-v2.9.0;`to it instead of using fetchurl. works but `nix-shell` would be better...

Comment: `nix-shell '<nixpkgs>' -A perlPackages.YAML` works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@danbst

```
nix-shell '<nixpkgs>' -A perlPackages.YAML
```

is what i was searching for! thanks